# Tomcat 6: change in context.xml, restart?

Tags: tomcat

I'm currently working in `Tomcat 6`. I know that if a change is made in `web.xml` Tomcat needs a restart but, what about the `context.xml`? Is a restart necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the [`reloadable`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) `<Context>` element configuration property set to `true` (the default is `false`), then the web application will automatically reload itself when you change `web.xml`. If you modify `META-INF/context.xml`, your wep application will automatically reload regardless of the `reloadable` setting.

In any case, you can always use the [Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html) web application to stop, start, undeply, re-deploy, etc. whenever you want. You can even script these reloads from the command-line if you'd like.